# Open Excel Workbook and clone it in C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I need to access an Excel workbook read-only. Is it possible to open an Excel file, clone the Workbook instance for further use and close the file?

Comment: Without calling `Save()` there is no modification to the file. You are working on a inmemory version of the file. And you can use `SaveAs` if you want to safe it somewhere else.

Comment: Why not simply copying the file somewhere else temporary and use that one ?

Comment: Did you infact try to save it and get prompt with the readonly error?

Comment: Copying file into %temp% is exactly what I'm doing. Just thought I could further optimize my program by releasing any open files as soon I get all data I need. I've run into some shenanigans while trying to open it with Excel while my program was reading it as it just refused to open it.

Comment: As far as i can remember Excel doesn't have an override allowing to load from a memory stream which would have allowed you to not touch the actual file other than copying into memory the content. So you might end up having to use the temp folder trick. I would appreciate if someone has access to the library and could actually verify if this is still true that it doesn't allow for memory stream loading of a file.

Comment: Is the workbook protected, and if not, what is making it read-only?  Or, is the workbook open and are there protected sheets?  I assume you have a C# program reading the contents that also needs to do other stuff -- if that's not the case, please clarify.

Comment: It's not protected. I only need to read data, no modifications are made.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand your problem...  if you only need to read it, why clone it?  Why not just read the read-only version?